# set escape on then issue host command in SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

The command `set escape on` would enable the escape character.

```
SQL> select '\&' from dual;

'
-
&

SQL>
```

But when issue a `host` command, I can't understand the behavior.

```
SQL> host echo foobar aa
foobar aa

SQL> show escape
escape "\" (hex 5c)
SQL> host echo foobar \&
foobar

SQL> host echo foobar '\&'
foobar &

SQL>
```

Why does using `'\&'` instead of just `\&` change the output?

Comment: Quoting of the string literal?

Answer (score 1):

& is a substitution character

The & is translated as this and is just waiting for more (translated into nothing).

```
SQL> host echo &
SP2-0317: expected symbol name is missing


SQL> host echo 1
1
  <- One line returns
SQL> host echo \&

   <- two lines return
SQL> host echo 1 & 2
Enter value for 2: 3
1 3
```